# Plotly express choropleth_mapbox is not working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, choropleth

I found the solution to this question:
The locations and center arguments need to be filled. The following code works.

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    geojson=gdf_json,
    color=df['Number_Neddle'],
    featureidkey="properties.neighbourh",
    locations=df['neighbourh'],
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    center = {"lat": 53.543727, "lon": -113.494654},
    zoom=10.5
)
fig.show()
```

Thank you for whoever helps.I am really frustrated.

I have been trying to build a choropleth map using plotly choropleth_mapbox. But it always shows as blank.

I have one dataframe with two columns.

```
df=pd.read_csv('Downloads/Neighbourhood/neighbourhood.csv')

df.head()

   neighbourh  Number_Neddle
0      1010.0             90
1      1020.0             46
2      1030.0           1559
3      1070.0             50
4      1090.0            463
```

neighbourh is the neighbourhood id and number_neddle is the number of needles collected in that neighbourhood.

Then I have a json file transferred using shapefiles.

```py
    with open ('Downloads/Neighbourhood/neighbourhood.json') as f:
        gdf_json =json.load(f)
    
    gdf_json["features"][0]["properties"].keys()
```

```
>>> gdf_json["features"][0]["properties"].keys()
dict_keys(['neighbourh', 'descriptiv', 'descriptio'])
```

then, I tried to design the map.

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    geojson=gdf_json,
    color=df['Number_Neddle'],
    featureidkey="properties.neighbourh",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron"
)
fig.show()
```

The result I get is:

[image: just a completely grey image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `gdf_json`?

Comment: Is there insufficient location information? Please refer to [this page](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#choropleth-map-using-plotlyexpress-and-carto-base-map-no-token-needed).

Comment: The 'neighbourh' in the data file must be a string. So we need to convert it to an integer and then to a string. At the same time, the geojson file side also needs to be a string.